# How can I add a custom Netty channel handler in Vert.x?

Tags: netty, vert.x

The docs only mention Netty, but I can't find a way to access e.g. the `ServerBootstrap` or get a hold of the channel.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to add a custom channel handler to servers created by Vert.x.

However you can integrate servers created manually with Vert.x contexts/verticles.

See http://www.julienviet.com/advanced-vertx-guide/#integrating-netty

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. Netty is an implementation detail of Vert.x